# Should I flag old questions that ought to be closed?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, old-questions

I often use the [new answers to old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions?page=1) page.  Mostly I like to seek bad answers that should be voted for deletion.  Occasionally the answer itself is a sign that the question is bad and should be closed.  I of course vote to close, but being such an old question, it is unlikely to get attention.  Historically, I've been also flagging it for moderator attention, and explaining in a custom message why the question should be closed.  One moderator has disagreed with this tactic:

[image]

The moderator thought that I shouldn't use flags for this -- I should rely on my ordinary close vote.  But the difference in practice between the two is large.  Previously, old questions that I flagged to close from this process resulted in closed questions.  The following are questions that I flagged for moderator attention to close (and that were closed or deleted):

- [Code Golf: Conway's Game of Life](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499538/code-golf-conways-game-of-life)
- [GIS: PostGIS/PostgreSQL vs. MySql vs. SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743632/gis-postgis-postgresql-vs-mysql-vs-sql-server)
- [Version Control for non-programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665214/version-control-for-non-programmers)
- [How to set up a cvs server on windows 7 64 bit [deleted]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874992/how-to-set-up-a-cvs-server-on-windows-7-64-bit)

These were all consecutive questions I've flagged that were all closed.  Since this admonition from the moderator, I've declined to flag questions for closure.  None of them have been closed:

- [What software should I use for manually drawing schema diagrams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031991/what-software-should-i-use-for-manually-drawing-schema-diagrams)
- [How did/would you "force" yourself to do TDD rather than TAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731179/how-did-would-you-force-yourself-to-do-tdd-rather-than-tad)
- [Is Embarcadero C++ Builder a good choice as an IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230518/is-embarcadero-c-builder-a-good-choice-as-an-ide)
- [Is it correct to use single quotes for HTML attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242766/when-did-single-quotes-in-html-become-so-popular)

Most of these close votes have since been (automatically) deleted.  I believe it's fair to say that the nature of the questions that I suggested for closure are similar between those that were closed and those that were not.  It seems clear that flagging a question to be closed proves decisive for actually getting the question closed.  Since I believe it's useful to get these questions closed, and since it's also unlikely that they *will* get closed unless I flag them, I am requesting confirmation on what the appropriate behavior is.

Should I flag *old* questions that are unlikely to otherwise be closed for moderator attention?

Comment: If you want an old question closed, your best bet is to take it to the appropriate chat room. My guess is that moderators don't like to cast unilateral close votes on borderline questions. And using close votes will get nowhere if they don't show up in the review queue.

Comment: @Mysticial, I haven't used chat for this, but I'd be happy to do so.  Can you suggest what the appropriate chat room might be?  Is it tag-specific, or site-specific?

Comment: That part is tricky. At the very least you want to pick the chatroom that at least matches some of the tags. (i.e. don't go begging for close votes for a PHP question in the C++ room) It also helps if you're a chatroom regular as not all chatrooms will welcome drive-by-linking.

Comment: @Mysticial, hmm, I'll do my best.  But given the generic nature of this spelunking (new answers to old questions), I suspect I will be in drive-by mode most of the time.

Comment: I'm a regular in the notorious C++ room, and I regularly ask for help to nuke new answers to old questions. It works - but probably because I'm a regular.

Comment: In the past, moderators have said flagging old or otherwise under-seen questions for closure is A-OK: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89851/, e.g. (Searching on the term "close velocity" might turn up more instances.) That view may be obviated now by the close vote review queue, though.

Comment: this question is really better suited to be posted on Meta Stack Exchange, but it is also relevant to local governance policies.

Comment: your title should probably read "For old questions, Should I flag for moderator attention when I think it ought to be closed."

Comment: The proper behaviour here probably differs much with moderator to close-flag ratio on different sites. I don't have much insight into the close vote queue ranking algorithm, but maybe a change here could be the solution to this specific problem; however I don't know what other things this would break.

Comment: I think the answer is implicitly "no" based on [Is closing old questions a gigantic waste of time and effort?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254402).

Comment: If the question hasn't been answered, you can downvote to enable roomba-deletion of questions with negative score and no answers.  This doesn't help in your case, but if a downvote is otherwise warranted, is an easier way to get rid of old crappy questions.  If a downvote isn't warranted, leave it be!  Maybe the right expert will come along tomorrow.

Comment: @Jeffrey, if leaving the question for "the right expert" were viable, then the question shouldn't be closed in the first place!

Comment: You look like you have enough reputation to cast your own close votes.  Why do you need to flag for a moderator to close it?

Comment: @SamIam, did you read my question at all?  I was *extremely* clear, I think, that these old questions are not getting closed.  **Of course** I am casting my own close votes, which is why I explicitly said, "*I of course vote to close*" at the top of the question.

Answer (score 22):

If an off topic question is attracting answers that show up in review queues, it is by definition causing problems. Thus, closing or history locking is **not** [a waste of time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254402/1495539), and flagging makes sense. You might want to include the reason the question came up in the flag description.

However, don't go hunting for such questions just to have something to flag. Many will never cause problems.

Also, the normal close queue should take care of them on other sites where the queue is usually empty, so only on SO would flagging be required.

Answer (score 17):

Closing old questions that do not comply to actual standards is never a loss of time. Such questions are even more problematic than the new old topic questions because they are often highly upvoted and provide **bad example** for new users.

A newbie comes to the site, finds one of that questions and thinks

> hey, that question received XX upvotes, it's the way one should ask here

and then that newbie is angry and disappointed when his question get closed...

(of course, most new users, unfortunatelly, don't read FAQ and don't read example question, they just bump their 'assignment' wherever they can, but it's another issue).

However, flagging them may not be the best idea. There is a limited amount of mods and their time is quite precious. I'd simply vote them to close and when the community disagrees with your vote, simply put the problem to the meta. Meta posts can attract other people who will vote to close, or, alternatively, someone will provide the reason why the question shouldn't be closed (which can be agreed or disagreed by others).