# Should we flag for moderator attention after close votes expire?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

I was looking over some past flags and noticed that my flag on https://stackoverflow.com/q/17174498/1281433 with the message

> Non-reproducible. Running the query at the endpoint returns 1, not 0.
>   It looks like it was an intermittent outage. – Joshua Taylor Jun 12 at
>   2:12

was declined:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention

I flagged because I'd cast the corresponding close reason (following) earlier in the question's lifetime, but it expired so, insofar as my abilities are concerned, this does require moderator intervention.  (I *didn't* mention this in the flag reason, though, and I *should* have.  That mistake is mine.)

> This question was caused by a problem that can **no longer be reproduced**
>   or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be
>   on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
>   future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely
>   inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem
>   before posting.

It's still definitely not-reproducible, but the question has enough views that close votes are expiring.  Since it's not reproducible, it's not likely to help future users.  **What should we do to get questions like this closed?**  Is the right answer "be sure to mention the expired close vote in the flag reason"?

This is similar to, but not the same as:

- [Should I flag old questions that ought to be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250060/1281433)

Comment: No. Waste of mod time.

Comment: @bjb568 Well, it was a yes or no question, I suppose. :) Any thoughts on how we *should* get questions in low-traffic tags closed once they've had enough views that close votes can expire (so even if enough people vote, they don't end up voting in a short enough period of time)?

Comment: Chat, I guess. You can go to [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I removed that question, with a note to the author; beyond being unlikely to help anyone else, the title was broad enough that I suspect it could prove a stumbling-block to folks with other problems.

That said, I wouldn't normally consider something like this a pressing problem; you could've just as easily left a comment for the asker politely suggesting he remove his own question.

Now, on to your broader question...

**Do *not*** flag every question where your close vote expires. Most of the time, such questions have already been through review, and have been seen by multiple people who *could* have voted to close but explicitly chose not to. Asking a moderator to override them is likely to be declined.

If you care to make a strong case for why a given question needs action, something *beyond* "I think it should be closed but my vote expired"... Then it is ok to flag.

But remember: your responsibility here is to convince the moderator handling the flag, who likely does not have a lot of time or the inclination to dig deeply into the question's history, that it should be closed... And remember that several other people have pointedly *not* been convinced by the evidence in the question itself... **So make sure that you're presenting a *very* compelling argument.**

Comment: If controversy, meta.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire says "flag for a moderator attention". So, who should I believe more?

Comment: You scared me, @Oleg - I thought for a minute I'd written that myself. On the off-chance you do go find another answer somewhere *by me* that contradicts this, the general rule should be "whatever I wrote most recently"; I mostly just try to describe how things actually work, and that changes over time. Anyway, I added a clarifying note to that answer.