# Why is my question being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I have a SO question [How do I declare empty variables with self in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509455/how-do-i-declare-empty-variables-with-self-in-python) , being technically correct and overall sane.

Yet another time I get downvotes out of nowhere, which would be OK by itself, but

1. because of this I have a ban warning
2. I can see questions that can
   be answered by opening the language manual on first search occurrence
   upvoted to +300 and their replies as well.

Isn't it kind of strange? The questions that are considered strange by someone are downvoted, and therefore I cannot have use of the site in full. The questions which are just a information request are upvoted, despite the fact topic starter has done literally nothing to get his/her answer himself?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250060/should-i-flag-old-questions-that-ought-to-be-closed

Comment: If this is opinion based (I don't know Python at all, so I'm relying on what you've said), it should be closed as such.

Comment: As I just commented on the quesiton, it's absolutely unclear what you actually want to achieve. it's not "overall sane" at all, and it's not "opinion-based" just because you throw an "is this pythonic" in there.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that you don't get a ban warning for just *one* bad question...

Comment: @AstroCB He doesn't have just one bad question.

Comment: @Servy That was my point.

Comment: @AstroCB I see nothing in the OP to indicate that he feels this is his only problematic question.

Comment: @Servy I just meant that too much emphasis was put on `because of this I have a ban warning`.

Comment: **FYI, there are numerous spelling and punctuation issues with [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509455/how-do-i-declare-empty-variables-with-self-in-python).**. Don't fix them yet, I'm in the middle of doing that ***for you*** right now...fixed.

Comment: @l4mpi "I want something like ... Is there a way to do it?"
Is this hard to understand? Or you just dislike that the question is on anther level of interest that you expect,and therefore - it's not sane? As you correctly said, I've had this situation few times earlier, and I was thinking I'm doing stuff wrong. But now, I just want to get a clear understanding what is needed for my question to be let alone waiting for someone who bothers to read and answer the easy question?

Comment: I've got 2 answers overall, and I've accepted this answer. Why is my question edited and but on hold as unclear(!!!) if I have two nice answers with code samples that even got upvotes?

Comment: @ror6ax the fact that an answer matches what you need doesn't mean your description was _not_ unclear. As I showed in my comment in your question, there are at least 4 ways to interpret your question - of course one can take a guess or just answer all of the interpretations but that's not exactly useful. You gave a vague and ambiguous description of a requirement, without a specific example of what you actually wanted to achieve (what's the purpose of having an "empty" attribute?), which you now cleared up a bit with your edit, but the first revision was certainly unclear and thus not useful.

Comment: But regarding your edit, "C-like behaviour" is still not really clear because that's actually not "empty" at all, just either initialized to 0 or a random value - see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6212973/1110381). Also, python is not C; there are concepts in both languages which simply do not exist in the other, thus the question seems somewhat like an XY problem as you simply try to apply a C concept to python. For future questions, if you don't know how to apply something you know to a new language, you should focus a bit more on your goal than the specific concept.

Answer (score 7):

Posts aren't voted on purely for being technically correct or incorrect.  The voting tooltip for your question states:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

So the people that downvoted appear to have felt that you didn't do sufficient research before asking your question, that it wasn't clear, or that it wasn't a useful question.

Comment: Okay, I got it. 
I can write class in Python, I know the usual way do to it, I ask if another way is available and is "right" in the terms of style and stuff. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation

This on the other hand literally says "Guys, please re-tell me the documentation" and gets 490 upvotes.

Comment: @ror6ax The fact that someone else asked a bad question and got upvotes doesn't meant that you can ask a bad question and get upvotes for it.  Some bad questions get upvotes.  I'm not going to lie and say otherwise.  *That* is the problem.  It doesn't mean you should emulate that behavior.

Comment: @ror6ax Your question sounds like this to me: Imagine you've only ever ridden a bicycle, then you buy a car, only to have it towed to the repair shop and you ask them "Where are the handlebars?"  There is an expectation that at a minimum you will understand the basics of using a language before you ask a question about it. Plenty of tutorials exist to get you to that point and I personally consider it a huge waste of time to have to answer such trivial questions when the answer is a google search or a skim of the documentation away.