# Does it make sense to close a question that was opened for 4 years+ and viewed 55 000+ times?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, old-questions

I just noted that one of the most popular question of mine was closed this summer after more then 4 years. In the meantime it was viewed 55k+ times (without single vote for close). I was going to ask the moderator in comment whether it makes sense to close so old questions, but I realized Meta is better place for such question.

Let me just elaborate a bit before I ask:

1. Yes, by today's SO standard, the question clearly should be closed as off-topic.
2. At the time the question was asked, it was common to ask that kind of questions as SO rules were not so restrictive and well-defined (proved by the fact it stayed opened for so long despite number of views).
3. The question and its answers clearly provides some value to SO community given how many people have seen it. And please, bear in mind that by the community I mean here not just few top members with that of mine SO reputation (or even that of yours) who will answer this here on meta. It is also the average programer who might not even be registered user but uses SO day after day to improve their code. This is the majority of those who create SO traffic. To them old questions that do not follow today's strict rules might be more helpful then some of the new ones.
4. By marking the question with big **CLOSED** we are implying to programers described in 3. that they there is something incorrect about this question or its answers. They might not generally understand what closed means on SO.
5. It was very unlikely that somebody write new answer or comment to the question given its nature and age.

*Let me now ask*, why should we close this old famous (by SO terminology) questions? Wouldn't it be better to protect it or something like that (I do not remember what the other options are). It seems to me (correct me if I am wrong) that closed questions generate less traffic for SO, because average web surfer will just ignore it as incorrect. So why not to keep these questions *open* and use some other way to restrict new answers, so that they can be helpful to more people.

I have noted questions similar to this one have been risen before, but I believe I have made some new points here.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250060/should-i-flag-old-questions-that-ought-to-be-closed

Comment: The real problem isn't closing, but the deletion that will inevitably follow because some purist doesn't like that is no longer a appropriate question, even though it was fine at the time.  Questions like that help the site a lot as they draw a lot of people in.  It would be nice if they would apply more historical locks to questions like that, or even had a special state that didn't allow upvoting (of the question) but still allowed new answers, so that things could be kept current.

Comment: I stopped reading at _"Yes, by today's SO standard, the question clearly should be closed as off-topic."_. The answer, then, is **yes**. And that's all there is to it....!

Comment: It's ridiculous to close and/or delete any such question. It's "just silly".

Answer (score 11):

Of course it should be closed. We don't want more of this type of question posted, and the close message clearly explains that.

Comment: Please read my question again. I do not think this kind of questions should be posted on SO anymore (1.).

Comment: @drasto: Which is the reason it should be closed, just like Andrew said.

Comment: @Deduplicator Closing a new question asked by unexperienced user will teach them that such questions should not be asked. By closing this old question I honestly did not learn anything I did not already new for few years. It was just a coincidence I even noted the question was closed. Closing only prevents new answers (which I hope can be achieved otherwise) and IMHO might have some unwanted effects described in my question.

Comment: @drasto: But you are not the sole audience for that closure. Others see that question and think "Yes! That's the way my questions must look."

Comment: @drasto By closing a new question only that user will learn the lesson. Closing an old question, which many people will see because of the question's traffic, will spread the idea to more people.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, preventing bad examples. But what about that message of closing the answers might be incorrect?

Comment: @drasto, I'll be frank, that question was very localized to begin with. The "correctness" of these answers can only be acknowledged by you since you were looking for a very specific tutorial (your question makes me think of the "what was that book/movie again?" ones on [scifi.se]). I believe that question could actually be *deleted* without the community losing much in the process, and I'm not a "deleter" kind of guy.

Comment: @drasto What about the closure message indicates in any way that the answers are incorrect?  The message is very clear about what it means, and it says nothing about the curacy of the answers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I am not so sure. I believe this might be worst question I asked on SO. Counting those early ones when people were asking about anything and rules were vague, community new. Yes, it is not even asking to recommend documentation for given purpose, it is asking about a specific documentation to specific library. So really bad, useless. But it looks like I am wrong and it *is* useful to somebody. Actually, to many. IT profs, including the best ones often forget the others might think different. Maybe others were also looking for the very same documentation because it was moved...