# Should this non-programming question be migrated or protected?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have come across the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470787/please-help-me-understand-size-vs-size-on-disk.

This is a popular question but is not about programming. Under the current rules of the site this would be closed as off-topic. I think that it would have a better home on SuperUser but perhaps because of its age it just needs protected status?

What is the correct course action for an "off-topic" legacy question?

Comment: By protected, I assume you mean locked?  Because protected just blocks low-rep users from posting, while locked prevents all from posting.

Comment: See also: [Should I flag old questions that ought to be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250060/2359271)

Comment: Questions greater than 60 days old cannot be migrated to other sites, the feature is even unavailable to the moderators.

Comment: The question is closed now, but will probably reopened shortly (sits at 4 votes).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- It cannot be migrated, it is older than 60 days. It'd require a developer to migrate that and that only happens rarely.
- It doesn't need protecting because it doesn't appear to be attracting low-rep junk answers; *protection* means something very specific on Stack Overflow (locking down a post to prevent answers from anyone with reputation below a threshold).

The question is simply off-topic and should be closed. I've voted to close it as:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

If there is no pre-existing question on Super User, you could post *your own version* there, but I strongly suspect the subject is already covered there in other posts. I'd not copy it over verbatim, not without proper attribution at the very least.

If you were asking for a historical lock, that is strictly reserved for posts with a controversial delete/un-delete voting history, where the post is already voted as off-topic. It is used to preserve popular but now-off-topic posts when there has been a clear history of community-led preservation of the post.

Comment: There is however several post in SU that cover this, for example [How can the size on disk be smaller than size?](http://superuser.com/q/518414) [Why is there such a big difference between "Size" and "Size on disk"?](http://superuser.com/q/704218)

Comment: @Braiam That kind of intricate knowledge on how file systems work is of great value for me as a programmer. Being selfish, I would vote to keep questions/answers that help me design programs/systems in a better way even if they may technically be off-topic.

Comment: Well, there are other places you can get the information, a google search for "Size vs Size On Disk" has SO at the top but SU is 4th (with a better question and better answers).  The 2nd link is a howtogeek ripoff of the SU question/answers and the 3rd is a technet article that does a good job of explaining it.  I don't think it belongs on SO.

Answer (score 11):

There is also the [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for), which indicates a question is an interesting one but not a valid SO question.  It exists largely to allow these questions (with valuable answers that many people have put time into, and gain something from) to not be deleted.

It's not appropriate in every case - it should be, and is, used rarely - but if you feel the question should be locked, either post on Meta to that regards (so we can discuss it) or flag for a moderator so they can decide (particularly if it seems obvious).

Comment: I would interpret OP's question as being a "post on Meta to that regards (so that we can discuss it)".

Comment: I wouldn't disagree with that statement.

Comment: Historical locks are probably one of the worse ideas on Stack Exchange: you can't vote, edit or comment on the question or any of its answers. This is a major impediment when it comes to curating a knowledge repository like what Stack Overflow tries to be. Any mistake in questions with historical locks will just stay there forever, without any possibility to give any feedback (this is particularly problematic with incorrect or misleading answers that have been upvoted).