# Sanity check for question closure

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I stumbled across this question today:

[Ajax success event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969476/ajax-success-event-not-working)

It's 6 years old and has been upvoted highly (I'm not sure why).  The question would seem to be off topic as it doesn't contain a minimal, complete and verifiable example of the problem.  The title itself is a bit of a red flag for me.

The accepted answer doesn't seem to actually address the question as asked, but has obviously helped.

The question has been highly upvoted and has answers from several high rep users.

My gut would be to flag this to be closed, based on feedback on several questions e.g. [Should I flag old questions that ought to be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250060/should-i-flag-old-questions-that-ought-to-be-closed) but wanted a quick sanity check to make sure I'm not just being overly picky.

Comment: You can close vote it and see if 4 other members agree with you. I don't think those old questions require our attention unless they gather new answers that doesn't add anything new. The question is voted and viewed a lot so it is usefull. I see no need to take action. There are more pressing issues on the new stream of questions that need our moderation.

Comment: @rene - fair enough.  Voting done.

Comment: I feel like that Q&A could be edited into a very useful general reference question.

Answer (score 1):

I see almost nothing wrong with the question - it has sample code (default `$.ajax` call), one could add Fiddler trace of response, but it would be of no help to other people looking for similar problem do not know how to even get such information.

Answer provides likely reason of the problem. Applying it (response should contain data in matching content type) would solve problem for large number of cases where `success` is not called for something that seem to be working (i.e. service returning XML instead of JSON).

Title is actually quite perfect - "XXXX not working" is very common search (as you can see by number of views) - "improving" title will make it less searchable.

**The only problem** with question is OP asked something that no one actually cared about ("wish to display an error message if the email or username are occupied") - I think that can be edited out or adjusted to match "success is not called" answers.

Comment: Yes, but the question doesn't describe the fact that an error is occurring, or post any of the code for the server call that may help us to figure out why.  The actual answer is an educated guess as to what the problem is (as it is not specified in the question).