# What to do with an old question, now considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, flags, scope, old-questions

I was reviewing late answers and someone thought it was necessary to answer a question from 2010. I found the answer VLQ, but looking at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959856/learning-networking-fundamentals)  it was attracting opinionated answers because of how it is written. If someone would ask such a question today it would be closed very quickly as being off-topic.

I did flag the question as being off-topic, but how should we deal with these old questions, that the SO policies have caught up with?

After writing my post It did attract a dupe target, so I flagged it as being such.

Comment: By doing exactly what you did: flag/vote to close. You've done that, so now you can move on.

Comment: @ale as it is such an old post it would most likely not get enough attention for my flag to even surface in the flag queues. Side question would be if it is helpfull to close these old posts (which is fairly well argumented in the dupe target)

Comment: @Luuklag the flag should push it to the close vote queue though shouldn't it? Eventually someone will come across it and notice what you've noticed so it should be alright.

Comment: Could very well be, but as the dupe target also points out it most likely doesn't. However the META effect kicked in now.

Comment: Could not agree more with [otus's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262134). Don't go hunting for old questions to flag/close, but if they're attracting new answers you're seeing in review, then they are causing a problem and you need to deal with them. And it's always better to deal with the *source* of the problem, rather than each individual answer.