# Why are there old questions that are too broad and that are not closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calendar-table-for-100-years-in-sql). It has few details and indicates nothing about the reason why OP wants such output nor what they already tried.

Yet, the question has not been closed, while I saw some questions out there that:
• are elaborate, with some notes on what they did; and
• include the code of what they tried,
but that forgot to include just one thing. Maybe the database they are using, the IDE, or anything, but just one. These are shut down just 5 minutes after the question was asked. Why?

Is it because this question is rather easy to answer?
Is it so broad that any answers can be applied into it for brainstorming purposes?

---

*I'm not asking whether [I should flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250060) this old question that ought to be closed. Rather, I'm asking why this question was not closed around the time it was asked, or soon after.*

Comment: The question is seven years old. It would be unlikely to survive if asked today

Comment: @ivarni That's why I asked, why did this question survived 7 years? Is it because the admins back then are not doing their job and the admins now are more precise? more strict?

Comment: @gnat not a duplicate, but I'm confused because why is this question is not closed back then? when it has all the characteristics to be closed?

Comment: @Mr.J The community's opinion on what is allowed has become more strict over time.

Comment: [broken windows...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info)

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic then the admins back then are less strict perhaps right? thanks!

Comment: You should note, that there are usually no diamond mods (what you call admins) involved in closing question. This is done by regular users with the close-vote privilege.

Comment: @Mr.J I think a title edit would help to clarify the difference between this and the target dupe.

Comment: And the meta effect kicked in. I wonder how usefull it is however to close such old questions? They are not going to get roomba'd as they have upvoted and accepted answers and most likely attact little new posts. And if they do they are usually from new users, and those get thrown through audits, FWIW

Comment: If it has been harmlessly there for over 7 years, viewed 57,659 times, is there really need to close it now and risk it being deleted. I am sure some of the 60K people who visited appreciated the accepted answer.

Comment: It's not about the question, @Antony, [it's about sending a message](https://i.imgur.com/kD3bDoH.gif).

Comment: @ivarni No, this question merited closure even at the time it was asked.  There simply aren't enough people casting close votes to close every single close-worthy question that gets asked, and there never has been in the entirety of the site's history, as a result, if you spend the time looking you can find a close-worthy question asked at any point in SO's history.  Yes, SO's standards have changed over time, but not much, and the vast majority of the changes happened within the first year or so of the site's existence.

Comment: About the only time it's correct to say, "the site's standards changed" is when the question was asked in 2008.  It took a few months for the site to realize subjective questions didn't work in the site's format.  By 2010 the number of changes to the site are few and far between, and are not significant changes.

Comment: If they closed the question, there are 60K people who may not have found the answer

Comment: @Servy I think there have been significant changes in what questions are allowed here. Granted, you have been around a lot longer than me so you may know better, but  looking at the [top voted C++ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?sort=votes&pageSize=50) almost every question would either be closed or down voted today. But in the pre 2012 era they flourished. Just from looking at historical questions and the accounts of long standing high rep users it would appear there has been a dramatic culture change over time.

Comment: @Servy Maybe its just [Survivorship bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias) though

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic No, as mentioned, lots of questions that meet the criteria for closure *don't get closed anyway*, for numerous reasons.  Most extremely broad questions were closed, even at the time those questions were asked.  That doesn't mean they all were though.  You can find a small percentage of extremely broad questions not being closed even recently, just as you can find a small minority of extremely broad questions not being closed from 2012, and every other year of SO's history.  The rules didn't change, they've just *never* been able to be universally enforced.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea but its broad, maybe the OP just selected the answer because it has many votes, but used the MYSqlcode instead. nobody knows for sure because he didn't specified anything. It's just, maybe I'm just envious, because when I think of a question, write it for like 1 hour, post it here, then somebody will ask what IDE I am using, then they'll close it, but the answers and comments somehow made it clear.

Comment: You've got to love the "creative" interpretation of both the question asker's intentions and the site's attribution policy by the accepted answerer. Question: *How can I "store thousands of days" in a table in [an unspecified dialect of] SQL?* Answer: *Ah, I see that you're clearly trying to compute the dates of the Christian holidays respected in Norwegian work culture using a script in Microsoft SQL Server. Don't worry, I've got a script for that. Who wrote it? Oh, don't worry about that. I found it "on the net".* And apparently this interpretation was... good enough for the question asker?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- ### There's luck involved

  Questions aren't all given the same amount of attention - the number of people who sees a question, and whether those people would or can vote to close, is somewhat random - questions can slip through the cracks.
- ### Judging a question is subjective and inconsistent

  Everyone doesn't agree on how every question should be treated, so the treatment of a question will vary based on who's online and sees the question around the time of asking.

  Beyond that, any given user may think one question is more appropriate than a very similar question based on subtle differences that could be hard to define and may not even be related to quality, not to mention that it could be affected by their own mood.

  We can't tell you why any given set of users didn't close a question (but we can tell you whether closing or not closing a question was "right", by current standards).
- ### There were less rules, and we were less strict, in the past

  As the site has grown, and we were figuring out what does and does not work, the rules have changed.

  I wouldn't be able to tell you whether the rules applicable to this specific question changed since it was asked, but it's always a possibility to keep in mind when it comes to questions that are a few years old (although this should not affect whether or not we vote to close it today - all questions, old and new, are subject to today's rules).

  We may also have been a bit more lenient in the past, when there were fewer questions to deal with.

So you should take the fact that any given question is not closed with a pinch of salt, especially if it's an old question.

Comment: No changes to the site's rules have affected the close-worthiness of this question since it was asked.  Questions were expected to be sufficiently narrow even in 2011.

Comment: @Servy Which simply tells us the community itself has changed. It should go without saying that the rules were never 100% objective to begin with. So if a given rule hasn't changed then, ipso facto, our subjective interpretation and enforcement of it has.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy it really amazes me that 7 years ago, I can climb up the reputation in no time. With less restrictions and fewer worries,.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy No, it just means that there aren't enough people voting to close questions that merit closure, and never have been.  Questions asked today that are just as broad go without getting closed, just like they did in years past, and all of the intervening years.  There are simply more people asking close worthy questions than there are people casting close votes.  According to your logic if I can find someone from seven years ago that committed murder and didn't go to prison for it then our interpretation and enforcement of that law must have been different back then.

Comment: Luck does play a great part in all of this as well as time. There is a sweet spot where low-quality questions thrive and that is when most of the users online on SO are rep-whores but there is also a time when those low-quality questions are closed off instantaneously because the SO guardians are now awake. We'll call it timezone difference.

Comment: @Servy It seems we need to up our rep so that we can be eligible to cast those closing votes.

Answer (score 6):

Example of another OLD question that I attempted to close on the same day: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36885990/timeline. But it failed, **twice**, like maybe 95% of my regular<sup><sub>*</sub></sup> close votes, it got engulfed in the mass of the pending questions from the [close review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close).

So, on the "***Why** are there old questions that are too broad and that are not closed?*", I can't say for sure. I'm not in the head of those [57 695 viewers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calendar-table-for-100-years-in-sql), so I can only guess:

1. Because those questions are on Stack Overflow for historical reasons. [The close reasons evolve together with the community choices.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)
2. Because there are so many questions on Stack Overflow: [more than 15 millions currently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions). So we miss *that* one.
3. Because the CV queue is too big, it's like Monstro the Whale of Pinocchio or Uraya the Titan of Xenoblade Chronicles 2: it will swallow many but only kill few. [The CV queue has constantly between 8 000 and 10 000 pending questions!](https://stackoverflow.com/review) And after a few days, your close vote expires, wasted. (this behavior doesn't apply to delete votes for instance: delete votes never expire)
4. Because the community focuses its efforts on *active* questions in general, for various reasons: many askers will often have an immediate need for the answer and will abandon the question soon after, while answerers will often seek either to help those impatient askers or will seek to grab reputation points, which is statistically easier done when you're the first one to answer. As such, inactive questions get lower attention.

So, what can you do?

- Don't be shy to use your close votes on off-topic questions, but also don't forget to move on: it may or may not get closed in the end, but there is no need to worry about it.
- **Review the Close Review Queue as much as you can, every day!** ☺

<sup><sub>*</sub></sup>By *regular close votes*, I mean those for questions that I don't advertise on [socvr](https://socvr.org): the chat group https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers is an effective mean at closing questions, but is mostly targeting the new questions, not old ones, so I use it with economy/parsimony.

Answer (score 0):

The OPs, moderators, flaggers, we all are human; so, things are not always consistent. For me, I don't find a problem with an occasional broad question surviving. My problem is that perfectly valid questions get down-voted, then close-voted.

Let's try to be more inclusive. No need to grumble about the questions that did not get deleted, but it is better if we can help users to improve questions instead of close-voting them.

I personally think it is a good question that is not too broad. The question is short, but it asks about how to use SQL for one specific purpose. It is not like the OP asked "what is life after StackOverflow like?".

Comment: Good point though.. But this community isnt going to help anybody, so as long as the rules are not meant, but that is right now only, I think the past years, there where questions like this, but actually survived, or not monitored?