# What can be asked and what can't be asked?

Tags: discussion, moderation

When I search for a solution of my problem on Stack Overflow, I often see question like this:

- [Chrome dev tools slow down computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990060/chrome-dev-tools-slow-down-computation)
- [How to solve the error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol - function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886397/how-to-solve-the-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-function)
- [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)
- [Environment Variable is too large on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491244/environment-variable-is-too-large-on-windows-10)

I don't understand how these questions are allowed as they don't seem to follow the  [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as the authors of these questions do not show a way they tried to solve the issue they are having. What makes these questions respect the guide? I don't understand that as when I try to ask a question like the one I previously showed result in either getting my question moderated or downvoted.

My question is that how I can ask for my question properly if I have no clue how to solve it as in these cases I cannot provide a example of what I tried to solve the problem that I am having. This often result in me not asking my question at all by fear of getting banned from asking questions.

To clarify my question, here is a example:

> What is a input array for OpenCv? I see it all over the docs of opencv however I don't understand what it is. Can we show me a example of what it is?

Comment: Well for one thing, the second and third posts you linked are 7 and 10 _years_ old respectively. Times change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I flag old questions that ought to be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250060/should-i-flag-old-questions-that-ought-to-be-closed)

Comment: 1. There is a comment asking for debugging details. There are no answers - very likely because there aren't details. 2. Seems OK at first glance. There does seem to be enough information to understand what's wrong and how to fix it. 3. It's a historical question originally from over a decade ago. Also, with git specifically there isn't that much to show what you've tried in many cases.

Comment: The presence of older off-topic questions does not make new off-topic questions any more on-topic.

Comment: @JeanneDark No, it do not because I am wondering how I can format my question to be allowed in these cases. I sometime get error that I have no clue hhow to solve so I don't have any idea how to show something that I tried.

Comment: Nobody can help you improve your own question(s) based on old questions by others. Providing examples of questions of your own that have been problematic would be much better if you want assistance

Comment: This question needs more focus and details or clarity. What kind of questions do you want to ask? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @JeanneDark Question that do not show the ways I tried to solve the problem. I sometime have no clue how to solve an problem I am having (see the link I added)

Comment: @Nick I added an newer question

Comment: Since no one has said it yet, older questions aren't an indicator of anything aside what was allowed a decade ago. Using them as an indicator of anything is roughly the equivalent of digging up an old stone tablet that contains laws for an obscure civilization and applying it to today's society -- doesn't hold, won't happen. Only one of the questions you linked is relatively new, and even that's 5 years old and seems to relate to a semi-current event. Finally, some things slip through moderation -- when it's brought to the attention of people active in moderation (i.e. like this), they

Comment: tend to get hammered fast, and some times locked. Just because a bit of content is on the site that violates the rules, doesn't mean it should or that new content should do what it did.

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve with this Meta post @Vini? If your question really is "What can be asked and what can't be asked?", then please see the [help] ([What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)). Not every question requires to show failed attempts.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to get to understand better how I should ask question with no attempt. I would like to get more guidance.

Comment: Instead of adding links to unrelated questions you might instead include more info about what kind of question you would like to ask (maybe illustrate with an example).

Comment: I tough that 
> My question is that how I can ask for my question properly if I have no clue how to solve it as in these cases I cannot provide a example of what I tried to solve the problem that I am having. This often result in me not asking my question at all by fear of getting banned from asking questions.

was enough

Comment: If you want to know how to ask good questions, then use the [ask] article you linked to in your question and the resources linked at the bottom of that page (such as Jon Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)). (Although not everyone agrees on it,) "How to" questions are perfectly valid, assuming that the [other rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) apply and it is adequately scoped and contain all the necessary information.

Comment: 'I have no clue how to solve it as in these cases I cannot provide a example of what I tried to solve the problem that I am having.' Can you give an example of such a question?

Comment: Here is a example @MartinJames : What is a input array for OpenCv? I see it all over the docs of opencv however I don't understand what it is. Can we show me a example of what it is?

Comment: @JeanneDark I updated the post to include a example

Comment: *"What I am trying to achieve is to get to understand better how I should ask question with no attempt"* - research effort. It needs to be shown and it needs to show you tried your best to reference several sources to try and figure it out. You need to be able to show that you informed yourself properly, that you're not just trying random things for the heck of it to not have to make the effort. If you link to one random internet page and say "I read this but didn't understand it", you did not pass the test.

Comment: You answered my question. Thank you @Gimby :)

Comment: @ViniDalvino you're welcome. Just to note: I am of the opinion that "how to" questions which show no research effort can be acceptable questions that deserve to be upvoted if the answers to it are going to be useful to others. It's just that... well there seem to be more people who don't agree with that and I guess that is because they take the tooltip that you get when hovering the downvote button to an extreme literal sense. So it is in your own best interest to show all the effort that you can.