# Why has my old question been closed after 8 years?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons, old-questions

I asked this question more than 8 years ago:
[My programs are blocked by avast anti-virus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375340/my-programs-are-blocked-by-avast-anti-virus)

Today, it has been closed, with the reason "need more details".

May I ask why has this question been closed after such a long time?

Why is it today suddenly considered to be not detailed enough?
I haven't touched  it at all recently, and I don't see any reason to modify it now. After such a long time, what would I need to add?

I don't even understand why anyone would bother about that question. Why isn't it just left open in peace?

Do I need to do something to reopen it again?

Or is this normal, closed automatically for historical purpose, in an automatic cleaning process or something like that?

Comment: It had new activity and is too broad (three different programs are affected) and without the code we can't know what the anti-virus program reacts to. Not sure you can do anything about it or why you should. It's still around and can be visited by users and everyone involved still keeps their rep gains.

Comment: Posts are not closed _automatically_. Your question recently received an answer which has been deleted again. This new activity caused your question to receive some attention.

Comment: By virtue of being open, the question received an answer 20hs ago (since deleted).

Comment: Do you disagree with the closure? What exactly do you consider a problem here that needs Meta support?

Comment: I'm curious why you care that it's been closed and you'd apparently forgotten about it?

Comment: I wanted to know what's going on because it surprised me. I have got an answer on why it happened. That's all good now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I flag old questions that ought to be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250060/should-i-flag-old-questions-that-ought-to-be-closed)

Comment: @gnat The answer to [Should I flag old questions that ought to be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250060/should-i-flag-old-questions-that-ought-to-be-closed) imply that this old question maybe should have been left open in peace, but it is not a duplicate.  It is from the perspective of power users who might close questions, not from the perspective of somebody who got their question closed.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think it is just as relevant for askers because it helps them see that on one hand, indiscriminate hunting for their old questions is frowned upon and on the other hand, closure is normal and expected in cases when these get organically bumped to attention by some organic activity (like it happened here)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "*imply that this old question maybe should have been left open in peace*" I think you're inferring what was not implied. The top/accepted answer there says not to go *hunting* for old questions to close. However, when a question gets a new answer or gets edited, etc., it shows up on the front page... it gets thrust in front of our eyes. And if it's off-topic for some reason, it should be closed as such, even if it's 8 years old.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Users vote to close old questions that are off-topic in part to discourage similar questions from being asked today.

When an old question with many votes and multiple answers is closed there are two practical effects:

- There is a note at the top of the page saying the question is closed.
- New answers are not accepted.

Many things will still work:

- Your question and its answers will remain on the site.
- Users will still be able to find the question in search engines.
- It will still be possible to vote on the question and its answers.
- It will still be possible to edit the question and its answers.
- Nobody is going to lose the reputation gained with the question.

It seems unlikely that you still need new answers to this question, so I see little reason that you should try to get it re-opened.

Comment: I effectively don't wait for any new answer, and it doesn't make any sense either that I edit the question to make it compliant with nowadays SO requirements. So I'll left it closed as it is. Thank you for reassuring me about side effects.

Answer (score 30):

Stack Overflow gets a lot of questions. We have a long backlog. We apologize for the delay, but we run exclusively on volunteer labor.

Questions that are off-topic or otherwise unsuitable for this site should still be closed, regardless of age. There's no "statute of limitations" on content here. Just as new answers are always accepted, so are new votes to close. Yours just happened to reach the threshold today. Congrats!

You don't need to do anything, unless you actually disagree with the closure and think that you could *edit* the question to make it into one that is suitable for this site. Then, you should do that. This will put the question into a review queue, where volunteers will review it to see whether the edit solved the issues with the question that caused it to be closed in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

I was one of the close voters.

My criteria was the question and its answers are essentially about an anti-virus blocking several programs. It's not about the details of using a specific programming tool, nor about solving a problem specific to the GCC compiler. It's a general software PC question (that coincidentally affected some development programs.)

By definition that is on-topic on Super User

> [What topics can I ask about here? - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)
>
> - computer software, or

but not on-topic on Stack Overflow

> [What topics can I ask about here? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is

This does not mean the question isn't useful to readers or won't stay around. Closing the question in this case makes the site more organized and serves mainly to avoid continued answers expanding on the question because those contributions should be posted on the proper site which in this case is on https://superuser.com

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! I don't know much about superuser. Did it exited at the time I asked the question ? Does it mean that the question is going to, or should, be moved there ? At least now I know that I should ask such question in superuser rather than stackoverflow, for the future.

Comment: @QuentinC I'm not 100% sure how things went, but [Super User has been around since 2009](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/08/18/super-user-now-public/). I think the original split of Stack Overflow was into Super User and Server Fault.

Comment: I disagree. Some of the mitigations are to change the code of the application or [to sign it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375340/my-programs-are-blocked-by-avast-antivirus/14375532#14375532) (also part of developing the application). Code signing is an important part of developing (professional) applications for later versions of Windows (approximately from [Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista) (2007) and on).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I noticed that, I felt the answers brought the question closer to being border-line because the question itself could (and probably should) be further narrowed down. The question also seems close to *"needs clarity"* by modern standards  (E.g. mentions of the text editor further clutter the already verbose post, it doesn't include a concrete MRE, a lot of it seems Avast specific so we could argue it's a costumer support or SU question, etc...) All things considered casting a CV is not without reason in this case.